# Viscosity solution of the PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be bounded domain, $u=0$ on $\delta\Omega$ and
$$|Du|-f(x,u)=0$$

where $f\ge 0$ and $f$ is strictly monotone for fixed $x.$ I am looking for the reference to show that it has unique viscosity solution.

P.S. It has been posted before mathstackexchange.

Comment: What is $|Du|$?

Comment: This stands for gradient of $u.$

Comment: This is literally the first example I saw when I studied viscosity solutions in grad school. Have you checked the users guide to viscosity solutions for a general existence and unique theorem?

Comment: The answer already appeared here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278384/viscosity-solutions/279310#279310 

Comment: Yes, but the proof in math.stackexchange is wrong because the functions $\phi$ may not exist if $u_1$ and $u_2$ are not differentiable at $x_0$. The classical proof uses the doubling of variables method, very much like in the proof of Theorem 1 in section 10.2 of Evans book.

Comment: Indeed, the proof on MSE is wrong. Theorem 1,/10.2 is about uniqueness, but how about existence?
 I am trying now to adapt that proof for uniqueness result.

Comment: You can use Perron's method for existence (which is covered in the User's Guide). You can also check the book by Bardi and Dolcetta "Optimal control and viscosity solutions of HJB equations", as they study HJ-equations of this form.